# Read data from file with mixed length of arrays/vectors in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a file that in principal looks like this

```
1 2 2,3,4 5
6 3 7,8 9
10 5 11,12,13,14,15 16
```

4 columns where column 1 and 4 is integer/float columns but column 2 indicates how many elements that are in the vector in column 3, so column 3 is in reality a column that has different length vectors

How to best read in this and to best represent this structure in a "variable" / dict.
I have tried to use readdlm with the delim = "," and I can read in the file but needs to easily address the structure to get the integers/floats/arrays for plotting etc. In reality there are much more columns and rows and which columns that are variable sized vectors varies from case to case

Comment: Is the "," used to separate columns or to indicate floats? Either way its hard to figure out your example.

Comment: space as column separator and , as separator within coulmn 3 for array elements

Comment: it is totally unclear what you mean in this question. Maybe you could try to rewrite it to explain what you need?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not 100% sure what exactly it is you want to do. But if you want to parse the file into some datastructure, here's a jab at a solution:

```
function parseline(line::AbstractString)
    fields = split(line, ' ')
    v = [parse(Int, i) for i in split(fields[3], ',')]
    lenv = parse(Int, fields[2])
    lenv == length(v) || throw(DimensionMismatch("Incorrect length for $v"))
    result = Any[parse(Int, fields[1]), v, parse(Int, fields[4])]
    return result
end

function parsefile(path::AbstractString)
    return open(path) do file
        [parseline(line) for line in eachline(file)]
    end
end
```

The first function parses a line and checks if the length of column 3 matches the value in column 2. It returns a vector of [column 1, column 3, column 4]. The second function just does that for each line in a file.